# Are there an equivalent classes( TouchAction, PointOption - Appium classes testing a native mobile app) in Selenium v4.1.2.1 for swipe actions?

Tags: mobile, selenium4

I used below code in a work, where I conducted **'Swipe(direction)'** actions on both Android and iOS devices, to test a native mobile app.

Now the AUT is a website rendered in an Android mobile device on a cloud device farm. I need to swipe-up/down, and swipe-left/right for bringing Web Controls which are not in the view port due to longer display.

My ask is - are there an equivalent class(s) (preferably an example) in Selenium v4.12.1, which I am using to test the MobileWeb situation, I am dealing with right now ?

```
    /**
     * Swipe the mobile screen upwards so that hidden button comes into  visible zone
     * @param dir
     */
    public void swipeScreen(Direction dir) {
      System.out.println("swipeScreen(): dir: '" + dir + "'"); 

      // Animation default time:
      //  - Android: 300 ms
      //  - iOS: 200 ms
      // final value depends on your app and could be greater
      final int ANIMATION_TIME = 200; // ms

      final int PRESS_TIME = 200; // ms

      int edgeBorder = 10; // better avoid edges
      PointOption pointOptionStart, pointOptionEnd;

      // init screen variables
      Dimension dims = driver.manage().window().getSize();

      // init start point = center of screen
      pointOptionStart = PointOption.point(dims.width / 2, dims.height / 2);

      switch (dir) {
          case DOWN: // center of footer
              pointOptionEnd = PointOption.point(dims.width / 2, dims.height - edgeBorder);
              break;
          case UP: // center of header
              pointOptionEnd = PointOption.point(dims.width / 2, edgeBorder);
              System.out.println("pointOptionEnd UP derived");
              break;
          case LEFT: // center of left side
              pointOptionEnd = PointOption.point(edgeBorder, dims.height / 2);
              break;
          case RIGHT: // center of right side
              pointOptionEnd = PointOption.point(dims.width - edgeBorder, dims.height / 2);
              break;
          default:
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("swipeScreen(): dir: '" + dir + "' NOT supported");
      }

      // execute swipe using TouchAction
      try {
          // First change to 'NATIVE_APP' context
          shiftContext("NATIVE_APP");
          new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver)
                  .press(pointOptionStart)
                  // a bit more reliable when we add small wait
                  .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(PRESS_TIME)))
                  .moveTo(pointOptionEnd)
                  .release().perform();
          // Shift the context back to original
          shiftContext("CHROMIUM");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println("swipeScreen(): TouchAction FAILED\n" + e.getMessage());
          return;
      }

      // always allow swipe action to complete
      try {
          Thread.sleep(ANIMATION_TIME);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // ignore
      }
      System.out.println("Swipe Action complete");
  } 
// public enumeration.
  public enum Direction {
      UP,
      DOWN,
      LEFT,
      RIGHT;
  }
```